# Pandas - Substract columns from different data frames with mixed data type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames that are imported from different `.csv`.

```
df10=pd.read_csv(path10, usecols=["Registros validados"])
df25=pd.read_csv(path25, usecols=["Registros validados"])
```

They are 173k rows and one column, the data contained there are numbers, but there are empty measurements that when read from the `csv` are treated like an empty string (and so are the numbers for that matter).

What I need to do is simple, I need to subtract them only when both columns have a number and create a third dataframe.

Found two ideas that I got from other posts of this webpage. The following two are the ones that worked (gave me no errors), because what I mostly saw was `.apply`, but that was always for when the columns used were from the same dataframe, which they are not here.

The options that "worked" were

```
list(map(subs_PM, dfpm10, dfpm25))
# Returns ['']
```

and

```
dfpm10.combine(dfpm25, func=subs_PM)
# Actually returns a data frame, but is always empty with ''.
```

The substraction function used was

```
def subs_PM_old(pm10, pm25):
   try: # Thinking the strings would fail at this
       pm10=int(pm10)
       pm25=int(pm25)
   except: 
       return ' '
   else:
       return pm10-pm25
```

Thought maybe the discrepancies in the subtraction was due to the fact the dataframe wasnt of numbers. So I did the following to convert the numbers to numbers and leave the strings as strings.

```
df10=df10.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
df25=df25.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

and updated the function to be

```
def subs_PM(pm10, pm25):
    boolpm10=isinstance(pm10, (int, long, float, complex)) and not isinstance(pm10, bool)
    boolpm25=isinstance(pm10, (int, long, float, complex)) and not isinstance(pm25, bool)

    if boolpm10 and boolpm25:
        return pm10-pm25
    else:
        return ''
```

But nothing changed

What seems to be happening is that, in both cases, the function to subtract is being used only for the first row, and then assumed to be like that for the rest of the items.

Is there a way to change that?

---

Obviously these are not my dataframes but consider this to play around with

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({1: range(10)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({1: [2, 3, '', '', 2, 1, '', 6, 2, 3]})
df1.combine(df2, func=subs_PM)
df1.combine(df2, func=subs_PM_old)
list(map(subs_PM, df1, df2))
list(map(subs_PM_old, df1, df2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
def subs_PM(pm10, pm25):
    #pm10 and pm25 are series... not a single number
    #print(pm10)
    try:
        pm10=pd.to_numeric(pm10)
        pm25=pd.to_numeric(pm25)
        return pm10-pm25
    except:
        return None

df1 = pd.DataFrame({1: range(10)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({1: [2, 3, '', '', 2, 1, '', 6, 2, 3]})
df1.combine(df2, func=subs_PM)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works exactly as I wanted with one minor modification so that it is in agreement with the rest of my code.

Answer (score 1):

To check all variants, I defined the source DataFrames as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({1: [0, '',  2,  3, 4, 5, '', 7, 8, 9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({1: [2,  3, '', '', 2, 1,  5, 6, 2, 3]})
```

The goal was to have "pairs" of arguments, where either *df1* or
*df2* can contain a string (to be excluded from the final result).

Initial operations involve:

- join both DataFrames,
- replace empty strings with *NaN* and drop them,
- change the type back to *int*,
- give different names to both columns.

The code to do it is:

```
res = df1.join(df2, rsuffix='_2').replace('', np.nan).dropna().astype(int)
res.columns=['c1', 'c2']
```

For my source data, the result is:

```
   c1  c2
0   0   2
4   4   2
5   5   1
7   7   6
8   8   2
9   9   3
```

Then just compute the difference, saving it in another column:

```
res['dif'] = res.c1 - res.c2
```

The final result is:

```
   c1  c2  dif
0   0   2   -2
4   4   2    2
5   5   1    4
7   7   6    1
8   8   2    6
9   9   3    6
```

If you want, drop *c1* and *c2* columns.

Comment: Thanks! I liked your approach but unfortunately, I needed to keep the rows even if the difference didnt exist. A lot of little questions I had were resolved through your answer though. So thanks!